# Start uitabviewcontroller with screen not on tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My uitabbarcontroller has 5 tabs, but when the initial uitabbarcontroller is loaded I want to display a viewcontroller that is not any of these 5. I also want none of the 5 to be selected.

The most recent questions that I have found were for iOS 5 and in the comments they stated that you can no longer do the same methods or swift with throw an error.

Is there a way to initially load a uitabbarcontroller with a view not in the viewcontroller list (tab items)?

Comment: Do you want the view controller to be inside tab controller or when the view controller is shown, the tab bar should not be visible?

Comment: I have figured it out by making a viewcontroller with a tabbar, then once the tabbar is pressed it takes the user to a tabbarcontroller and based on whichever tab was pressed, it will load that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a viewcontroller with a tabbar placed at the bottom. This allowed me to load a start-up screen without having any of the tabs selected. Once a tab was selected, I used prepareForSegue and passed through the value index where I gave each tabbar item a different tag corresponding to the next page's (the tabbarcontroller) tabbarsitems

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    index = item.tag
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goToMainGroupScreen", sender: nil)
}
```

Then upon loading the next screen I selected which tab to make the first displayed by the value index.

Had to use UITabBarDelegate in order to do this